# Save latitude and longitude after converted into string in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, geolocation

How can i convert properly the lat and long into string and save it to db mysql?Any help is much appreciated.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
        public function addLocation(Request $request){
            $address = NGO::all();
            $address->lat = $request['lat'];
            $address->lng = $request['lng'];
            $lat = $address->lat;
            $lng = $address->lng;
            $address = getaddress($lat,$lng);
            $address->save();

            return view('pages.Ngo.Add-New-Ngo-Scholar');
    }

    public function getaddress($lat,$lng)
    {
    $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.trim($lat).','.trim($lng).'&sensor=false';
    $json = @file_get_contents($url);
    $data=json_decode($json);
    $status = $data->status;
    if($status=="OK")
    return $data->results[0]->formatted_address;
    else
    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Laravel to always cast a specific attribute to a string (or an array, etc...). You can even cast to JSON (in the db it will be json_encoded en saved like a string)...

For this use in the model:

```
protected $casts = [
        'attribute_name' => 'string'
    ];
```

Comment: Ok I'l try this first.

Comment: Sir,Ok How to combine the lat and long in my model.Like 'lat' => 'string' and 'long' => 'string'.It should be saved in one column in the table?

Comment: Saving them both in one column? That's up to you & completely depends on your purpose with this. Your question was about how can I save something in the database as string... :-)

But if you want it in two columns and cast to strings:

protected $casts = [
        'lat' => 'string',
        'long' => 'string',
    ];

Comment: Sir, to explain further,What i really want in one column is before saving the lat and long, it should be converted to string to look like the real address in string.Ex. lat- 23.456566,long - 10.4335500(This should be save as  (795 E DRAGRAM
   TUCSON AZ 85705
   USA)

Comment: Hi, I am sorry, because I can not help you with that. . Stackoverflow is not a site where people help you with programming. It is a site where you find answers to concrete questions (like: how to save a string in Laravel?)... I cannot help you program your application. Try searching on internet for sample code (search: sample code google maps api).

Comment: @ jeroenF - Its alright sir, i'l keep trying to find a way resolving this problem.